# HTTP TO HTTPS with AWS EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

My domain is registered on Namecheap, and bought SSL from NameCheap.
Server is on Amazon, EC2 instance. I have created a load balancer at AWS console provided SSL certificates and security group. Load balancer configured successfully, but i am not able to access my apis on HTTPS.

NOTE- i don't have much experience in back end things

Comment: Can you provide exact settings of your https listner and ssl cert? Also "i am not able to access " is not secific. Exactly what is happening, any error messages, screenshots, how do you even test it? Does it work with http only? How did you deploy your ssl on load balancer?

Comment: The same issue, although for me it's a 404 that's returning... I followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KtpiF3SUCkA&t=18s